# GWT : composite that fits to browser like any other web application

Tags: gwt

I am new to GWT and just started with layout for now.
I created a login screen (layout : in center of the page) and then after successful login moving to 2nd page that has doc panel and added few components to it.

When I launch this,it appears in the center of the web page. I want it to cover entire page depending on the size of the browser/screen.

How can I get there?
Please help.

Also please share any small GWT application (with source code) where navigation to 2,3 pages are used.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me. (Overlay being a div I want to cover the screen with).

```
    public void coverScreen() {
        overlay.setHeight(getHeight() + "px");
        overlay.setWidth(Document.get().getBody().getClientWidth() + "px");
    }

    private static native int getHeight() /*-{
        if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight && $doc.body.clientHeight) {
            if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight > $doc.body.clientHeight) {
                return $doc.documentElement.clientHeight;
            } else {
                return $doc.body.clientHeight;
            }
        } else if ($doc.body.clientHeight) {
            return $doc.body.clientHeight;
        } else if ($doc.documentElement.clientHeight) {
            return $doc.documentElement.clientHeight;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }-*/;
```

**EDIT**

I worked on a function to avoid covering the scroll bar.

```
 private static native int getScrollbarWidth() /*-{
    var body = $doc.body;
    body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    var width = body.clientWidth;
    body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    width -= body.clientWidth;
    if (!width)
        width = body.offsetWidth - body.clientWidth;
    body.style.overflow = '';
    return width;
  }-*/;
```

The setWidth call becomes.

```
 overlay.setWidth(Document.get().getBody().getClientWidth() - getScrollbarWidth() + "px");
```

The div CSS is as follows

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 6790;
margin: 0px !important;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
opacity: 0.8;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.  Could you please share the complete code  . It would help me to understand how to use the code mentioned by you in project.   Thanks again

Comment: I just did. Overlay is a Row element (I'm using GWT-Bootstrap). Hence, it's just a <div> tag. I call coverScreen() and overlay.setVisible(true) to display it. Is there something you can't reproduce ?